# How can I disable a button after it has been clicked in Vue Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue-native

I have a button in my template that does something on click. However, I want it to be disabled after the user has clicked it once.

Comment: Have you tried setting disabled=true on the button in the onclick?

Answer (score 0):

v-bind:disabled="newName === ''"

try this

Comment: Could you please give a clear example with context where it can be used?